# Most elegant way to achive the some element?

Tags: jquery

I wrote function onclick of `a` element

```
   <div class="left_collapsed">Որոնում</div>
        <div class="container" style="display: none;">
           <ul> 
              <li>
                 <a href="" id="search_refresh" >Թարմացնել համակարգը</a>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
   </div>

$("#search_refresh").click(function(u)
{
     how can i achieve to first div element here?
     (i have many div's with left_collapsed class )

});
```

i wrote
`$(this).parent("li").parent("ul").parent("div").before("div").addClass("left_expended");`

but i dislike it:)

Thanks much

Comment: there are many divs with same classes, so i need another method then `parents`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either use `.closest()`

```
$(this).closest('.left_collapsed');
```

or `.parents()`

```
$(this).parents('.left_collapsed');
```

Actually, `.closest()` is a better choice, since it'll only grab parent nodes **until** it reaches the desired one, whereass `.parents()` grabs **all** parent nodes (up to the document root).

Ref.: [.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/), [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closests/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery.parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/), something like this:

```
$("#search_refresh").click(function()
{
     var element = $(this).parents(".left_collapsed");
});
```

Update: jAndy's answer is better, you should use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead, particularly if the left_collapsed divs are nested such that #search_refresh is inside multiple left_collapsed divs.

Comment: as i mentioned, i have many elements with  `class="left_collapsed"`. i need exacltly that div.

Comment: Are those `.left_collapsed` elements nested inside each other?

Comment: Can't you just assign another (special) class to that particular `.left_collapsed` element?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parents('.left_collapsed');
```